# How to install tool in alpine docker

Tags: docker

I want to install some tools from linux in dockerfile

```
FROM python:2.7


COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y dnsutils

CMD ["python","test.py"]
```

I want to use python2.7-alpine in docker file.

I have used this code to install dnsutils but the result show failed

```
RUN apk update && \
    apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python-dev musl-dev && \
    apk add postgresql-dev
```

I want to install dnsutils tool and python2.7-alpine

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 3):

you can change the Dockerfile as follows

```
FROM alpine:3.9

RUN apk add --no-cache python && \
    python -m ensurepip && \
    rm -r /usr/lib/python*/ensurepip && \
    pip install --upgrade pip setuptools && \
    rm -r /root/.cache
```

For more information on the image you can follow: https://hub.docker.com/r/frolvlad/alpine-python2/dockerfile

To install dnsutils install bind-tools. Use the below code

```
FROM alpine:3.9

MAINTAINER QuangVu

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app


RUN apk add --no-cache python && \
    python -m ensurepip && \
    rm -r /usr/lib/python*/ensurepip && \
    pip install --upgrade pip setuptools && \
    rm -r /root/.cache

#RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

RUN apk add --update --no-cache bind-tools


CMD ["python","test.py"]
```

Comment: and how can I install dnsutils in docker?

Comment: you can use the following command in Dockerfile :
RUN apt-get install -y dnsutils

Comment: I get this error: 
"/bin/sh: apt-get: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y dnsutils' returned a non-zero code: 127"

Comment: can you share the content of your docker file?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please delete your answer